# Recommended ratio of storage for yb-tserver yb-master in YugabyteDB cluster

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

What's the recommended ratio of storage of yb-master to yb-tserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storage of both systems is not directly related.
The masters contain the cluster and YSQL metadata. The number of masters is equal to the replication factor chosen, and generally is 3. The masters use RAFT for voting a leader, and the leader is the active member of the RAFT group, the others are followers for the sake of high availability and read consistency.

The actual database processing is done by tservers. Each tserver provides an API for YSQL (postgres compatible) usage and for YCQL (cassandra compatible) usage. If no containers are used, it’s common to have a tserver started on the nodes with the masters.

For the number of tservers, it’s up to the resources that the database needs for having enough tservers. This is very flexible, and doesn’t follow a fixed pattern: you can have a low number of servers with lots of resources such as CPU, memory and storage, or more and smaller servers.